# How do I fix this error in python: [<_io.TextIOWrapper name='states.txt' mode='r' encoding='ANSI_X3.4-1968'>]

Tags: python, list, file, sorting

I am working on a lab where I have to open a file and then move the data into a list and sort it but I keep getting this error. I have seen a lot of people ask questions with the same error on stack overflow and I tried using those suggestions but everything I have tried has given me the same error, any suggestions? This is the code I have so far:

```
f = open('states.txt', 'r')
print(f.read())
states_list = []
states_list.append(f)
states_list = sorted(states_list)
for i in states_list:
    print(states_list)
```

Comment: Are you trying to read the file line-by-line? Can you post an example file/text of states.txt?

Answer (score 1):

`f.read()` pulls the contents of the file in as one long string, so you are trying to sort a list of one item. `states_list` probably ends up something like:

`['Here is how all the data in your file is going to look in a list\nAnd even more if it's on different lines\nLike this.']`.

If your states are on separate lines, you can append them to the list line-by-line like this:

```
f = open('states.txt', 'r')
states_list = []
for line in f.readlines():
    states_list.append(line.strip()) # strips newline character at the end of the line
for i in sorted(states_list):
    print(i)
f.close() # make sure to close your file!
```

Alternatively, this is a good opportunity to start using `with()`, which will automatically close your file after execution, as well as a list comprehension (which is cleaner here).

```
with open('states.txt', 'r') as f:
    states_list = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
for state in sorted(states_list):
    print(state)
```